# Need SQL join script for the Specified requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables commontypes  and Payments.

```sql
create table commontypes (type_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,descrip VARCHAR(MAX)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_commontypes ] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [type_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



INSERT INTO [commontypes ]
     VALUES
           ('GOV'),
           ('NON GOV')

GO

create table Payments(Payment_id int,Common_Type_id int ,amount int)

ALTER TABLE [Payments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_commontype_Payments] FOREIGN KEY([Common_Type_id])
REFERENCES [commontypes ] ([type_ID])
GO


insert into Payments values(1,1,0),(2,1,2558),(3,2,4556),(4,2,7882),(5,2,0),(6,1,0)

GO
```

I want all the results from joining the tables but exclude only type_id 1 and value 0 records(Two records) from the results. (other non zero amounts for type_id 1 and all amounts of type_id 2 should be available in the result).

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and publish a credible attempt.

Comment: select * from payments p inner join commontypes c ON c.type_id = p.common_type_id and not (amount = 0 and common_type_id = 1)

Comment: Thankyou siggemannen.It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From [comment by @siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75682685/need-sql-join-script-for-the-specified-requirement/75689136#comment133517892_75682685):

```sql
select *
from payments p
inner join commontypes c ON c.type_id = p.common_type_id
  and not (p.amount = 0 and p.common_type_id = 1);
```